# store handlers of a json objects in an array

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

I'm creating a texas hold'em gaming website and I have the relevant database in RoR:

```
    create_table "games", force: true do |t|
        t.integer  "player1_id"
        t.integer  "player2_id"
        t.integer  "player3_id"
        t.integer  "player4_id"
        t.integer  "player1_betting"
        t.integer  "player2_betting"
        t.integer  "player3_betting"
        t.integer  "player4_betting"
    end
```

Might not be the best set up but I'm using javascript to display current "on table bets" on the page in real time for each player. I have this game object above sent in as a JSON object and would like to loop through each of the bets. I would like to know if something like this is possible or just easier to make a new database for betting by itself:

```
    var releventGameHandlers = ["player1_betting", "player2_betting"...];

    $.get( '/games/' + gameID.toString()).success (function(g)  {

       for(var i = 0;i < releventGameHandlers.length; i++){

         $("#div").val(g.releventGameHandlers[i]); 
    });
});
```

Comment: must be g[relevantGameHandlers[i]]

Comment: ive never played texas holdem but i think it would be better to have player json objects, having a private and a public part. every player gets all public parts of the others and just his own private one. The players are connected trough a hoding table object

Comment: Jonas w: thanks for the reply I think that might work, really shaky on javascript more of a backend kind of guy. I had it connected to the player originally but got confused if someone had more than two games going on at once. Made me think that betting logic should be connected to the game and not the player. Otherwise having more than two games would make the db screwy. However, most texas Holdem sites only let you play one game at a time while I was thinking my game could be a "save and continue later" style. I should rethink overall layout again.